# What could cause Heroku application error even after adding Procfile to node project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, hosting

I recently added a MongoDB API to my node app hosted on Heroku and now I get an application error each time when I visit the link. I have added the Procfile to the root dir, added mongo_url to env config in Heroku and yet nothing. The app works when tested locally using the same port:5500 and mongo Atlas URL.

Here's the link to the repo: https://github.com/SimplyElvis/RESTful-api.

what could be the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the output of error ?

Comment: Because you don't provide such a thing so it's hard to say what's going on. First of all as i see, you don't provide nodejs and npm engine versions as was said in this article - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: Okay, but I provided the node version only.

Comment: Also, the app web deployed from my GitHub account.

Comment: -----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 34.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v17
       https://stack-rest.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku deployment is always successful but app never loads

Comment: Download Heroku CLI and execute command `heroku logs --tail`, because error means nothing or look to Heroku dashboard and find logs

Comment: Thank your sir. Just checked and noticed something
at Module.load(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
2021-09-18T00:06:48.359279+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-09-18T00:06:48.359279+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-09-18T00:06:48.359280+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-09-18T00:06:48.507099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1